# Structure of function that describes sine signal

Tags: wave

I need to create a vector of sine signal.

So I'm trying to figure out what the structure of the function that describe sine signal ?

For example the function   $\sin 2x$  meets the requirements?

If the answer is no, then what is the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you posted similar question 3 days ago, regarding your teacher claiming that $\sin 2x$ is not a sinusoidal function. Nevertheless this function is definitely sinusoidal. Otherwise how come we can say that signals [**can be decomposed**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) into sums of sinusoids (and cosinusoids)? You have plenty of orthogonal waves: $\sin x, \ \sin 2x, \ \sin 3x, \ldots$, and all of them are sinusoids.

The only thing that is coming into my mind, is that:

> Discrete-time sinusoid is periodic only if its fundamental frequency 
>   $f_0$ is a rational number

For a sinusoid with frequency $f_0$ to be periodic, we should have:

$$ \sin[2\pi f_0 (N+n)+\theta] = \sin[2\pi f_0 n + \theta]$$

This relations is true if and only if there exists an integer $k$ such that:

$$2\pi f_0N=2\pi k $$
or, equivalently:

$$f_0 = \dfrac{k}{N} $$

To determine the fundamental frequency of a periodic sinusoid, we express its frequency as above and cancel common factors so that $k$ and $N$ have no common divisors. Then the fundamental period of the sinusoid is equal to N.

So for example:

- $f_0 = \dfrac{31}{60}$ implies that $N=60$
- $f_0 = \dfrac{30}{60}$ implies that $N=2$

Thus if you define your discrete sinusoid to be:

- $\sin[2 f_0 t]$, or
- $\sin[\sqrt{2} f_0 t]$

then these are no longer periodic in digital domain. Why? Think of that in following way: each sample at start of the new period will be shifted slightly - it's not a rational multiple of $\pi$. Below is some plot for two signals:

- $\sin [2 \pi t]$
- $\sin [2 \pi \sqrt{2} t]$

Sampling frequency is $10 \ \mathtt{Hz}$ and upper time limit is $8 \ \mathtt{s} $

[image]

You can see a first sinusoid is periodic - every 10 samples (1 second) you get repeating pattern. On the contrary second one, of which fundamental frequency cannot be represented as a rational number (no way to decompose $\sqrt{2}$) periods are not the same - thus your signal has no period. Check the figure below for overlay of 11 periods:

[image]

Comment: Answer updated with some plots as promised.